# Booting Ubuntu 22 with kernel 6.2.0-32 is impossible

Tags: boot, kernel

I have both kernel 6.2.0-32 and 6.2.0-26 installed on my Asus Vivobook.  Since 6.2.0-32 install boot has been impossible. I think this may be a common problem as I'm seeing issues with Ubuntu: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490616 and Linux Mint: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=403618

Does anyone have any idea of a resolution? Forgive me I'm not the most expert Ubuntu user; still finding my way!

I've tried this:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image

rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic              5.15.0-43.46                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic              5.15.0-58.64                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic              5.15.0-60.66                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic              5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic              5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic              5.19.0-38.39~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic              5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic              5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic              5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-43-generic              5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-45-generic              5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic              5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-50-generic              5.19.0-50.50                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic               6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-31-generic               6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic               6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04              6.2.0.32.32~22.04.9                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

then

`sudo apt remove linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04`

followed by:

```
sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
```

And rebooting.  I'm now running on 6.2.0-26 and it works fine; but I'm unclear whether I should be worried about future upgrades breaking things again.  And if I should be sharing this information somewhere to help the community?

Comment: I'm unclear why this would be downvoted without comment - if I'm doing something unhelpful here then please advise.

Comment: Do you have any error message when the boot fails? What did you want to achieve when you uninstalled the generic-hwe meta-package?

Comment: There was an error message which repeated on safe boot about fingerprint USB2.0 - something I don't think my Asus actually has (maybe that's related?) I wanted to remove the 6.2.0.32 kernel so I could reliably log in again. It worked - but I fear the issue may repeat when my kernel next upgrades

Comment: Removing the meta-package will only prevent future updates and not remove installed kernels. If you want to go back to the non-hwe kernel, you'll need to install `linux-generic` and (after confirming that 5.15 works), remove all newer kernels. If you just want to skip 6.2.0-32, you can reinstall the meta-package when the next one comes around.

Comment: Oh this rings a bell - I think I subsequently uninstalled linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic as well.  Did I do a bad thing by uninstalling linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04?  Should I reinstall it?

Comment: linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic is working just fine BTW

Comment: If you want to receive updates in the future, then yes. But currently, this will bring you 6.2.0-32, again.

Comment: Right now I'm ignoring updates. Maybe I'll try my luck again in a month say

Comment: I've also tried reporting here in case useful https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.2/+bug/2036287

Comment: I get kernel panic when booting. Have to revert to .31

Comment: Looks like others are experiencing the issue as well https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.2/+bug/2036287